# Why does the wedge product produce a scalar and not a graded element?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Reading the definition of the geometric product we get that it satisfies:

$$ a_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge a_r = \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{\sigma \in G_r} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{\sigma(r)} $$

Which if I understand properly is $1/r!$ multiplied by the sum of all permutations of the vectors (adjusted for the sign of the perumation).

I am trying to better understand this. My knowledge of the wedge product is basically as a mechanism to construct $k$-vectors, like $e_1 \wedge e_2 = e_{12}$. But this seems to be outputting a scalar?

This confuses me.

Comment: You should understand the right hand side: how do you multiply vectors?

Comment: Why would this output a scalar?

Comment: @Claudius depends on the product?

Comment: could you clarify on what $r$ is, if it is the dimension, what I suspect I can clarify nicely and straight forward.

Comment: @Enkidu it's the number of elements in the wedge. if you look at the left hand side the last entry in the wedge has an index of r. It;s not the dimension. For what is worth, I got it from the wiki entry on geometric algebras:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Comment: Note that the quantities $a_{\sigma(i)}$ are not scalar components but $k_{\sigma(i)}$-vectors (mutiplied together geometrically).

Comment: @Abezhiko Maybe you made some typos but "$k_{\sigma(i)}$-vectors" doesn't make much sense. What we have here are $r$ separate vectors $a_1,\dotsc, a_r$ which are being multiplied together on the RHS using the geometric product; these intermediate products can contain $k$-vectors for any $k = 0, 2, \dotsc, r$ if $r$ is even or $k = 1, 3, \dotsc, r$ if $r$ is odd.

Comment: For example: $$a_1\wedge a_2\wedge a_3=\frac16\Big(a_1a_2a_3+a_2a_3a_1+a_3a_1a_2-a_3a_2a_1-a_2a_1a_3-a_1a_3a_2\Big)$$

Comment: I also don't see why you think the result is a scalar.